# Alternatives to Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with attachments and found the java mail api to be irritatingly insufficient.

There are only two implementations of `javax.activation.DataHandler` which mandates me to create a local file to send an attachment. May be I have to write my own implementation of DataHandler but I dont want to do that at this point.

thanks in advance !

Addy

EDIT : I meant `javax.activation.DataSource` not `javax.activation.DataHandler`

Comment: Can you implement it yourself, perhaps? I found Java Mail to be insufficient aswel.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring provides a <strike>[partial wrapper around the JavaMail API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/mail.html#mail-javamail-mime)</strike>, making it a bit easier to swallow.

For example, the `MimeMessageHelper` class allows you to add attachments using various interfaces, [including from a general `InputStream` source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#addAttachment%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource%29).

The underlying mechanics of JavaMail are very comprehensive and robust, it's just the API that's rubbish. This addresses that concern, to a large degree.

Comment: Yup, thats almost close to home, if you dont mind MBs worth of jars. !!

Comment: In Spring 3, the mail stuff is in the context-support JAR which, together with its dependencies, is going to be relatively small (certainly not MBs)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html#Sending_emails_with_attachments) for this task?
It has [MultiPartEmail](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/class-use/MultiPartEmail.html) which has several overloaded `attach` methods.

Comment: Oh thanks for that ! But even this Class wont take a String as input and send it as an attachment ! It has to be either from a file or from a URI.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a custom DataSource is pretty easy (I tossed one together for one of our apps a year ago, and it took less than an hour).  If that's the only issue you are having with JavaMail, I suggest that you give it a try.

That said, I agree that JavaMail is definitely overly complex for the most common use cases.