# Is there any Java mail client library other than Sun micro JavaMail API?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to Java Mail API.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093924/alternatives-to-java-mail-api)

Is there any Java mail client library other than Sun micro JavaMail API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093924/alternatives-to-java-mail-api

Comment: Do you want a new API, or a new implementation of an existing API?

Answer (score 0):

[Geroa](http://geroa.ettrema.com/index.html) Found this one online

> Geroa is a java library which enables email server functionality,
>   without requiring knowledge of email protocols.
>
> It exposes email protocol operations as methods on a simple API, which
>   can be easily implemented by you. Protocol support currently includes
>   POP and SMTP, but work is underway on IMAP.
>
> Geroa also includes a MimeMessage parser which simplifies manipulating
>   emails which contains text, html and attachments.

Comment: Link is dead...