# difference between simplemailmessage and MimeMessageHelper

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I want to know when to use which message class in spring for sending email.

`org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage`

`org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use attachment you consider use MimeMessageHelper, but it is only a utility class. To send this kind of message consider using MimeMailMessage

SimpleMailMessage, this class allow to send emails with simple CC, Bcc, subject and text. No attachments

Check [this.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the [Koitoer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710771/1544069):

From [MimeMessageHelper Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html):

1. Mirrors the simple setters of [SimpleMailMessage](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/SimpleMailMessage.html)
2. Allows for defining a character encoding for the entire message, automatically applied by all methods of this helper class.
3. Offers support for HTML text content, inline elements such as images, and typical mail attachments.
4. Supports personal names that accompany mail addresses.
5. SimpleMailMessage has primarily 1 constructor where as MimeMessageHelper has 6 constructors with various combination of Multipart and encoding.
6. As of Spring 3.2,MimeMessageHelper has 57 methods where as SimpleMailMessage has 23 methods.

From google search: [Mail Attachments support by spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094088/1544069)